# Flutter Material Icons changed after upgrading SDK to 2.2.1 (latest stable)

Tags: flutter

I just upgraded my SDK and some Material Icons changed to this ugly ones, any advice?
[image]

Comment: do you have uses-material-design: true in your pubspec.yaml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the material icon codes where replaced in this SDK and I was using IconData instead of referencing by their name. So I updated the code to be like:

```
Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded, size: 20)
```

See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84427

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when your pubspec.yaml file, under dev-dependencies has `uses-material-design`set to false and its not including the material icons in your app.

Change it to true, and restart the app. It should work after that.